# First conditional with "Be going to"

Tags: verbs, conditionals, future-constructions

I would like to know if the following sentences are correct.
I know "WILL" should be used in the main clause, but is it also possible to use "to be going to"?

Examples:

1. If she finishes her homework today, she's not going to have any
   tomorrow.
2. We are going to be late if you don't put your shoes on right now!
3. If he keeps writing, he's going to be a good writer.
4. If you join that course, you're going to meet new people.
5. We are going to be late for the concert if you don't hurry!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: will changes the formality slightly, and the meaning. Right now, those are straight futures.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all of the sentences you wrote are correct and idiomatic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).